# Which toolbox for Belief Propagation and other inference methods in graphical models?

Tags: inference, graphical-model

Which open-source software (toolbox) do you think is the best for modelling graphical models (e.g. factor graphs), and doing inference on them? (the language doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

Another is the gRain package in R.

Answer (score 0):

I found LibDai very useful: 
http://staff.science.uva.nl/~jmooij1/libDAI/

Also Factorie is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had written [PyGModels](https://github.com/D-K-E/graphical-models) in Python capable of doing inference over LWF Chain Graphs:

It is quite lightweight as it depends only on standard library. However for heavy lifting, I suggest:

- [pgmpy](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy)
- [pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate)

The development on PyGModels is very active and documentation severely lags.

However there is a stable release which had appeared in JOSS:

Eraslan, D. K. (2021) ‘PyGModels: A python package for exploring probabilistic graphical models with graph theoretical structures’, Journal of Open Source Software, 6(61). doi: 10.21105/joss.03115.